# Where to find the Google Maps API library source code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to find the non-minified/uglified source code for the Google Maps API client library (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js).

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) only references this script, which dynamically downloads additional scripts. 
The Github [Googlemaps](https://github.com/googlemaps) organization repos only contains supporting libraries source code, so that isn't helpful as well.

Is the source code for the Javascript library available?

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps is the commercial product and because of this you can not find source code except this **[link to the library](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js)**.

**Following links will help you more:**

- **[Google Maps FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq)**
- **[Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/)**
- **[Maps JavaScript API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)**
- **[Google Maps on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps)**